# Automating a user sign in to scrape data after logging in with Playwright

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright, playwright-python

I'm trying to scrape simplify for it to login into my account and keep sending me matches it finds to my slack/telegram bots later on. I'm finding a problem with entering the sign in after I input my email and password and I'm confused as I've tried everything I can think of

I tried using `page.keyboard.down("Enter")`. I also tried using `page.click(button[type="submit"])` and it's not working so far.

```py
p = sync_playwright().start()

browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)

page = browser.new_page()

page.goto("https://simplify.jobs/auth/login")

page.get_by_placeholder("Email Address").fill("spam@gmail.com")
time.sleep(2)
page.get_by_placeholder("Password").fill(""myuniqpassword")
time.sleep(4)

page.click("button[type=submit]")
time.sleep(15)
page.screenshot(path="screenshot.png")
p.stop()
```

Comment: Don't use `sleep()`, use a real predicate like `wait_for_selector()` or `wait_for_function()`. What problem are you having exactly? It's sort of hard for me to repro this since I don't have credentials to this site, but if I fix your typo and run this, it works fine for me in that the button is triggered (and of course I get an "Incorrect email or password" banner). Please clarify the actual problem/behavior you're seeing on your end.

Comment: you figured out what exactly I was trying to sort and yes it worked, thank you!
side note I also added a ```wait__for__selector``` for the dashboard after it login so I can appropriately see it myself